# How to setup variables for fake user profiles in Figma

Tags: website-design, figma, prototyping

I have a fairly content heavy prototype and I’m using variables for fake data but I feel like im using it in a way that is probably not the best way?

For example, I have a collection called “Fake Data”. In there, I have Users. In Users I have Modes such as “Full Name”, “First Name”, “Last Name”, “Phone Number”, “Email”. This lets me update a whole user profile and its updated everywhere and keeps all the “user’s” information together.

However, modes doesnt seem “right” for this? It definitely works but one very large limitation is that there’s caps to how many modes you can have and unless youre enterprise its very limited.

Is this the best way to achieve what Im trying to do or are there better ways to handle this type of use case without the Mode limitations?

Example of how its setup with variables:

[image]